# HTML/PHP Form Select Option with link to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I followed a previous question on here to get a drop down with link to MySQL. It works without the form but with the form, all the `room_id`'s just scatter across one line and don't go in a drop down box. Any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you

```
//Creates a form for room_id
echo "<form action=''>";
echo "<select name='room_id'>";
//Creates drop down box to show the current rooms vacant
$sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
$sql.= " WHERE room_vacant = 1";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
echo "<select name='room_id'>";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['room_id'] . "'>" . $row['room_id'] . "</option>";
} //Closes drop down box
echo "</select>";

//Submit button
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";

//Closes form
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: You have 2x `echo "<select name='room_id'>";` remove one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know I didn't even realise, my fault sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problemo. Glad it all worked out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cheers for pointing it out for me haha, my eyesight is awful, struggled to find it even when you pointed it out

Comment: Because you are echoing out your select twice

Comment: Don't sweat it, even I made the same mistake at some point *in the past* ;-) Cheers

Comment: @Jack Consider accepting Tommy's answer to wrap it all up ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I was going to but I had to wait a few more minutes before I could haha ;) cheers for being polite I've got some proper rude replies in the past

Comment: You're very much welcome Jack. Like my momma used to say, *"People treat you nice, do the same and don't bite too hard"* ;-) cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are echoing your select twice. Remove one.

```
//Creates a form for room_id
echo "<form action=''>";
echo "<select name='room_id'>";
//Creates drop down box to show the current rooms vacant
$sql = "SELECT * FROM room";
$sql.= " WHERE room_vacant = 1";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['room_id'] . "'>" . $row['room_id'] . "</option>";
} //Closes drop down box
echo "</select>";

//Submit button
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";

//Closes form
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Now you have enough rep to give comments, which your answer is in the form of a comment. Do rephrase that to "Because you are echoing out your select twice".

Comment: don't I lose my last reputation points if I remove this answer?

Comment: I have modified your answer Tommy. OP can accept it now.